# Python 2.5 (PyPy) compatible web server / framework

Tags: python, python-2.5, pypy

I'm looking for a simple Python framework/library for creating a website run using PyPy.

So far, I'm using web.py, so that's the feature set (a bit a templating, sessions, input processing, that's it) I need for this project. Very minimalist, if possible.

web.py is not unfortunately not compatible with Python 2.5 (at least the Python 2.5 implemented by PyPy).

*Edited to add*: The solution should be able to run applications (light on the views, models, etc., heavy on the computation) reasonably well. Security is not an issue, but on my machine, every 20th or so request of the integrated web.py server didn't get answered, leaving a blank browser page. This would be unacceptable.

Is there something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) is a good web python framework and compatible with Python 2.5.

[Running Pylons on top of PyPy](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2008/06/running-pylons-on-top-of-pypy.html)

Comment: Will take a look. Their web server (Paste) seems to be production-usable, other than Django's.

Answer (score 7):

I've been using [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) with success on PyPy.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndPyPy), Django can be run on PyPy.

Comment: The django folks discourage (using ALLCAPS LETTERS) use of the integrated webserver in a production environment. Do you know any details? Security is not an issue, but it should really be able to run stable (what the web.py integrated server didn't, at least on my machine)

Comment: @Daniel - the web server provided by django is only for testing/development purposes. It would not hold up under the load of a real site with real traffic, is not as robust as a web server designed for the purpose of being a web server, supports no modules, etc. etc. etc. When you want to launch launch your site to the public, you will want to run PyPy through something like WSGI or FastCGI via a server like Lighttpd, nginx, or apache httpd.

Comment: @birryree Thanks for the info. Load would be light(ish), internal to an organization. I had major issues with web.py's server, where every nth request was just discarded. But of course I would prefer alternative approaches for running a website using Pypy.

Answer (score 1):

I was researching this today, and the best web server I've found that runs on pypy is [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/). Performance is pretty good. I've been using [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html), which is a very nice little framework that also works great with pypy.